# Driver development

Tags: driver

I want some tuitorials and suggestions from ma friends regarding the driver development of 
an LCD(colour 3'*3')  driver and an Audio driver.

Because am new to this domain.I have written my own drivers for UART's in DM 320 board.

Also i need some basic concepts of the same.

Renjith G

Comment: For which operating system are you looking to develop these drivers (assuming, of course, that you are not developing the drivers for a 'bare metal' system)?

Comment: our own embedded OS(confidential),which is something  similar to vxWorks

Comment: @  Brandon E Taylor 
my board is TI's OMAP 3530. ther an audio and an LCD parts are present.

Comment: and ma processor is ARM Cortex A8

Answer (score 2):

@LazyBoy gives good pointers for Windows; if it's for Linux, try [this online book](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/). In either case, in the future, *please* specify which operating system you have in mind!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look here

1. [Driver Development Part 1: Introduction to Drivers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx)
2. [Audio Driver Development Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909946.aspx)

Comment: The one on The Code Poject is the best you could ever find. And trust me, I've searched A LOT ;)